# Describing my Parser type as a series of monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have to describe the Parser type as a series of monad transformers.
As far as I understand, monad transformers are used to wrap monads into another monad. But I don't understand what is the task here.

Comment: Hint: take a look at some other monad transformers, like `StateT`, `ErrorT`, as well as the `MonadTrans` type class.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so the task here is to wrap the Parser around some other monad? (Like, if I understood correctly, ErrorT helps to deal with errors in other monads, so my ParserT should help to parse inside other monads)

Comment: @KadaFuite No. Basically, `Parser` is equivalent in functionality to a monad transformer stack; it is your task to find this stack. Hint: as you have defined it, a parser is something which applies a function to a `String`, while possibly failing with an `ErrorMsg`.

Comment: @bradrn I still don't understand. Could you please elaborate your first sentence?

Comment: Do you need to define a `ParserT` monad transformer, or simply define `Parser` in terms of existing monad transformers?

Comment: `ErrorT` is deprecated, isn't it? Look at `ExceptT` instead.

Comment: @chepner define Parser in terms of existing monad transformers

Comment: @KadaFuite Have a look at http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html, which also uses the example of decomposing a parser into multiple monad transformers. (But try to implement it yourself before looking at their solution!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a new type for `Parser`, you can simply define it as a type *alias* for a type created by one or more monad transformers. That is, you definition would look something like

```
type Parser a = SomeMonadT <some set of monads and types>
```

Your task, then, is to determine which monad transformer(s) to use, and what the arguments to the transformer(s) should be.

Comment: Or better, a newtype around a monad transformer stack.

Comment: @chepner should it be something like this:
    
    newtype Parser' a = Parser' (StateT String Either ErrorMsg a )
                    deriving ( Functor, Monad, Applicative, Alternative ) ? (Only this doesn't compile)

Comment: Close; `type Parser a = StateT String (Either ErrorMsg) a`; `Either ErrorMsg` (one expression) is the monad that `StateT` requires as its second argument. I'm ignoring `newtype` for now because `StateT...` already has the necessary instances. I'll happily defer to an answer that provides the benefit of wrapping this in a new type, though.

Comment: @chepner thank you, I think I got it! this is really better than writing all the instances. I didn't realise until now how cool monad transformers are

Comment: I must say this is quite hand wavy. There's no real code, no examples, no explanations, just a line of pseudocode that, if I were the OP, would mean absolutely nothing. "_Your task, then, is to determine which monad transformer(s) to use_" is actually the question. left unanswered.

Comment: That's intentional. I wasn't going to write the code for the OP, only clarify the task as was asked for in the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Before we begin to define combinators that act on parsers, we must choose a representation for a parser first.

A parser takes a string and produces an output that can be just about anything. A list parser will produce a list as it's output, an integer parser will produce `Ints`, a JSON parser might return a custom ADT representing a JSON.

Therefore, it makes sense to make Parser a polymorphic type. It also makes sense to return a list of results instead of a single result since grammar can be ambiguous, and there may be several ways to parse the same input string.

An empty list, then, implies the parser failed to parse the provided input.

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

You might wonder why we return the tuple `(a, String)`, not just `a`. Well, a parser might not be able to parse the entire input string. Often, a parser is only intended to parse some prefix of the input, and let another parser do the rest of the parsing. Thus, we return a pair containing the parse result a and the unconsumed string subsequent parsers can use.

We can start by describing some basic parsers that do very little work. A `result` parser always succeeds in parsing without consuming the input string.

```
result :: a -> Parser a
result val = Parser $ \inp -> [(val, inp)]
```

`item` unconditionally accepts the first character of any input string.

```
item :: Parser Char
item = Parser parseItem
  where
    parseItem [] = []
    parseItem (x:xs) = [(x, xs)]
```

Let's try some of these parsers in GHCi:

```
*Main> parse (result 42) "abc"
[(42, "abc")]
*Main> parse item "abc"
[('a', "bc")]
```

Say we want a parser that consumes a string if its first character satisfies a predicate. We can generalize this idea by writing a function that takes a `(Char -> Bool)` predicate and returns a parser that only consumes an input string if its first character returns `True` when supplied to the predicate.

The simplest solution for this would be:

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = Parser parseIfSat
  where
    parseIfSat (x : xs) = if p x then [(x, xs)] else []
```

Using the previously defined `item` parser (this requires a `Monad` instance for the type `Parser`, which I leave to you as an exercise):

```
sat p =
-- Apply `item`, if it fails on an empty string, we simply short circuit and get `[]`.
  item >>= \x ->
    if p x
      then result x
      else zero
    parseIfSat [] = []
```

Now we can use the sat combinator to describe several useful parsers. For example, parser for ASCII digits:

```
-- import Data.Char (isDigit, isLower, isUpper)
digit :: Parser Char
digit = sat isDigit
```

You get the idea. You start by defining elementary parsers, and use those to build more complex parsers. The type `Parser` shown here is actually `StateT` Monad Transformer, it combines `State` and `[]` in this case.

The code shown was taken from [here](https://deepsource.io/blog/monadic-parser-combinators/).